# Tablet recommendation for using QField

Tags: qfield, hardware-recommendations

I would like to use QField.

Which tablet is recommendable (waterproof, robust, good battery life, good camera)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a Samsung ActiveTab 3 and an ActiveTab Pro. Have been very happy with both so far, especially since they both support S-Pen for freehand digitizing. Don't know many other tablets that do.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, any tablet will do (we use the quite old Galaxy Tab A 10.5) which is still fast enough for large orthofotos with 10cm spatial resolution. More important for real field work is a shock proof case with shoulder and hand strap (we use the one from BRAECN which comes aroudn 30€ and is absolutely worth it!)